# Subtract a given date from sysdate to get the number of days

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to do something like this

```
 v_target_date := trunc (sysdate) - trunc (TO_DATE (iv_target_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM'));
```

but i am not getting what i am looking for ? I want to see what is the difference between current sysdate and the given date in days ? so if its over a month i should get 30+ days etc ...

I want to apply the logic based on the number of days passed from the given date and the sysdate. if its more than 48 hrs (2 days), I can apply logic 1 otherwise logic 2

Comment: Subtracting two `DATE` types will give you the number of days, so you should be getting what you want. What's your starting `iv_target_date` value, what do you get, and what do you want to get? What do you get instead? Is the number slightly too low - maybe you want to `trunc` the result rather than the two dates? What types are `v_target_date` and `iv_target_date`? It looks like `iv_target_date` is a string, since if it was a `DATE` you'd be doing an uneccessary `TO_DATE`, and if `v_target_date` is a number then it's a slightly odd name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a cutoff of 48 hours, I find the `INTERVAL` function to be more readable. You can do it like this (I've left out the truncating; apply it as necessary):

```
dateMinus48Hours := SYSDATE - INTERVAL '48' HOUR;
IF TO_DATE(iv_target_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM') < dateMinus48Hours THEN
    ... more than 48 hours ago
ELSE
    ... not more than 48 hours ago
END IF;
```

Or you could use this; you'll get the same result:

```
dateMinus48Hours := SYSDATE - INTERVAL '2' DAY;
```

Comment: what is the data type for dateMinus48Hours ?

Comment: Sorry; just now saw your question. It's a `DATE` type.

Answer (score 0):

48 hours is just 2 days, so a simple alternative is:

```
IF TO_DATE (iv_target_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM') < SYSDATE - 2 THEN
  -- logic 1
ELSE
  -- logic 2
END IF;
```